# Swift to C# convert?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to interpret Swift code to C# code. But last two lines failing.

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  let registry = Registry(queue: nil)
  registry.delegate = self
  registry.desiredType = [desiredType.IP]
}
```

C#:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {
  base.ViewDidLoad();

  Registry registry = new Registry(null);
  registry.Delegate = this;
  registry.desiredType = desiredType.IP;

}
```

**ERROR:**

> ViewController.cs(23,23): Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'ViewController' to 'IRegistryDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)
>
> ViewController.cs(31,31): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Foundation.NSString' to 'Foundation.NSSet' (CS0029)

Comment: Is `this` a `IRegistryDelegate`? The second error is outside of the code you have shown.

Comment: `[desiredType.IP]` That's an array/set. And the error says  that `desiredType.IP` is a NSString (`Foundation.NSString`) and not a `NSSet`.. Also, did you make your ViewController conforming to `IRegistryDelegate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ViewController.cs(23,23): Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ViewController' to 'IRegistryDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)

Just like we wrote in Swift ,ViewController should inherit from interface(Protocol in iOS) and assign it to the `Delegate`, then override the delegate method , don't forget to use `Export` attribute .

```
public partial class ViewController1 : UIViewController ,IRegistryDelegate
{}

[Export("AAA:")]
public void AAA(object obj)
{
    ...
}
```

> ViewController.cs(31,31): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Foundation.NSString' to 'Foundation.NSSet' (CS0029)

`desiredType.IP` is string here  which doesn't match  `[desiredType.IP]`(it is NSSet), you should use a `NSSet` instead to contain the string.

```
registry.desiredType = new NSSet(new string[] {desiredType.IP});;
```

Comment: You are very good knowledgeable. Not a single person could answer my question but you did exactly. Appreciate it